# Regex: Match a substring in all lines, except when the substring is inside a comment section

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Here I go:

I'm coding a PHP application, and I've got a new official domain for it, where all the FAQ are now located. Some of the files in my script include help links to the old FAQ domain, so I want to replace them using the new domain. However, I want to keep the URLs linking to the old domain only if they are located under a comment or comment block (I still use the old domain for self-reference and other documentation).

So, basically, what I want to achieve is a regular expression that works given the following:

1. Match all the occurrences of `example.com` in all lines*.
2. Don't match the entire line, only the `example.com` string.
3. - If the line starts with `//`, `/*`, or " *" don't match any `example.com` instance in that single line (although, this might be a problem if a comment block is closed in the same line where it was opened).

I usually write my block comments like this:

```
/* text
 * blah 
 * blah
*/
```

That's why I don't want to match "example.com" if it's situated after `//`, `/*`, or " *".

I figured it would be something like this:

```
^(?:(?!//|/\*|\s\*).?).*example\.com
```

But this has one issue: it matches the whole line, instead of "example.com" only (this causes problems mainly when two or more "example.com" strings are matched in a single line).

Can someone please help me fix my regex? **Please note: It doesn't have to be a PHP regex, since I could always use a tool like grepWin to locally edit all the files at once.**

Oh, and *please let me know if there's a way to generalize block comments in some way, like this: once `/*` is found, do not match `example.com` until `*/` is found. That would be extremely useful.* Is it possible to achieve it in general (non language-dependent) regular expressions?

Comment: Do you really mean "when the line *includes* `/*`" etc. instead of "when the line *starts with* `/*`? Imagine a line `This is example.com /* comments starts here` - now you *would* want `example.com` to be replaced, right?

Comment: You can do it in two steps: Separate the input into *comment* and *non-comment* tokens and then apply your processing on the *non-comment* tokens.

Comment: What kind of files do you want to process?

Comment: @Gumbo PHP, mostly. If I need to process other types of files, I could just use the same pattern and change the comment characters.

Answer (score 2):

A regex that only matches `example.com` if it's not inside a comment section (but that does not care about line comments, so you'd have to do this separately):

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%example\.com # Match example.com
    (?!            # only if it\'s not possible to match
     (?:           # the following:
      (?!/\*)      #  (unless an opening comment starts first)
      .            #  any character
     )*            # any number of times
     \*/           # followed by a closing comment.
    )              # End of lookahead
    %sx', 
    'newdomain.com', $subject);
```

Comment: @Gumbo: It *should* fail, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think only if inside `/* … */`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Erm... not really.

Comment: @user1560611: But you wrote in your question that you DON'T want to match `example.com` if it's situated after `//`, `/*`, or `<space>*`.

Comment: @Tim Oh, yeah, that's right. Sorry, I interpreted " \*example.com" in my mind as if it was not inside a comment section. Technically, what Gumbo said is right, it should not be matched when " \*" is inside "/\* ... \*/", but matched when " \*" is not inside a comment. Although, that's not strictly necessary for what I need to do.

Comment: @user1560611: I've rewritten the regex. It should now handle block comments correctly. It can't handle line comments, though. And you won't be able to get both in a PHP regex because of the lack of support for indefinite-length lookbehind. But if you could convert all your line comments into block comments first (which is easy), then you could use this regex.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It still matches "example.com" even if it's after " \*" or "/\*", though. Thanks for taking some of your time to help me, I appreciate it! Let's just forget about the "//" comments, since that would conflict with URLs, given "http://...", unless there's a way to state _not_ to match "//" _only when_ it is at the start of a line _and_ still select "example.com" and not the whole line.

Comment: @user1560611: Not if there is a following `*/`. Of course, the comments need to be properly closed and unnested for this to work.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Could you please add the following to your answer?
Most of the URLs I need to replace are on lines that _start with_ " \*" (obviously, inside a comment block, but that doesn't matter for the following).

So, which regex (not necessarily PHP) would comply with the following:

1. Match "example.com" ONLY WHEN it is NOT located after " \*" AND ONLY IF " \*" is at the start of the line.
2. The selection should be the matched "example.com" string, not the entire line.


Thank you. This is the last time I'll bother you. :)

Comment: This is neither possible nor necessary (either you have the line-based approach, but then you can't check whether you're inside a block comment, or you have the block-based approach, but then you can't check the line's contents the way you want). As long as comments are properly formatted, you don't need to check for `<space>*`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use some kind of tokenizer to tell comments and other language tokens apart.

As you’re processing PHP files, you should use [PHP’s own tokenizer function `token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all):

```
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
```

Then you can enumerate the tokens and separate the [tokens by their type](http://php.net/tokens):

```
foreach ($tokens as &$token) {
    if (in_array($token[0], array(T_COMMENT, T_DOC_COMMENT, T_ML_COMMENT))) {
        // comment
    } else {
        // not a comment
        $token[1] = str_replace('example.com', 'example.net', $token[1]);
    }
}
```

At the end, put everything back together with `implode`.

For other languages that you don’t have a proper tokenizer at the hand, you can write your own little tokenizer:

```
preg_match_all('~/\*.*?\*/|//(?s).*|(example\.com)|.~', $code, $tokens, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($tokens as &$token) {
    if (strlen($token[1])) {
        $token = str_replace('example.com', 'example.net', $token[1]);
    } else {
        $token = $token[0];
    }
}
$code = implode('', $tokens);
```

Note that this does not take any other token like strings into account. So this won’t match `example.com` if it appears in a string but also in a ‘comment’ like:

```
'foo /* not a comment example.com */ bar'
```